# What if I delete ibdata1 in mysql (LINUX)

Tags: mysql

I am using LINUX and I have mistakenly deleted ibdata1 file in mysql folder.

I restarted the 'mysqld' service and Now when I am trying to read data from the databases it is not able to find out older tables.

Am I in a big trouble? Please throw some light on this if any idea.

Thanks for your time.

Thanks and Regards,
SachinJadhav.

Comment: +1 out of sympathy. You're screwed. Your last chance would be to attempt to undelete the files using eg. debugfs. But it's quite likely you've already written enough to the partition to ruin any chance of recovering the data intact.

Answer (score 6):

You are in big trouble...

By default ibdata1 contains all the table's data (and therefore is lost). Even if you configure it to use a separate file per table, all internal MySQL's data is stored in that file, and as far as I know, there is no way to restore it.

Really hope you have a backup....

Answer (score 1):

Unless you defined `innodb_file_per_table`, this is a single tablespace that along with the transaction logs (stored in `ib_logfile*`) keep your table data.

Deleting it will effictively delete all data stored in the `InnoDB` tables.

Comment: Is there any way I can restore the this file?
I am deadly looking for the data(if it is there in that file)

Regards,
Sachin Jadhav

Comment: @CachinJadhav did find a way to do so at the end? my only hope from looking at this situation, is to be able to rebuild the data from the log files (depending on what type of info is recorded there).

Answer (score 0):

if `innodb_file_per_table` is enabled then the tables can be restored via [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57120/recover-mysql-database-from-data-folder-without-ibdata1-from-ibd-files/57157#57157) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93507/alter-all-tables-discard-tablespace/93511#93511).

## Blatent copy of https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57157/189538

### MyISAM

For a MyISAM table mydb.mytable, you should have three files

- `\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mydb\mytable.frm`
- `\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mydb\mytable.MYD`
- `\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mydb\mytable.MYI`

They should already be accessible as a table since each file contains needed data, metadata, and index info. Collectively, they form the table. There are no external storage engine mecahnisms to access.

### InnoDB

Take a look at this Pictorial Representation of InnoDB

[InnoDB Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EcRi.jpg)

The only thing that attaches ibdata1 to the `.ibd` files is the data dictionary.

Your mission, should you decide to accept it, is to create each table and swap in the `.ibd`

Before you do anything, make a full copy of "\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data" to another

Here is a sample

Suppose you have a database `mydb` with the table `mytable`. This means

- You have the folder `\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mydb`
- Inside that folder, you have

  - `mytable.frm`
  - `mytable.ibd`

You need the `.frm`. If you look at my post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44314/how-can-extract-the-table-schema-from-just-the-frm-file/44316#44316, you can download a MySQL utility that can generate the SQL needed to create the table.

You should now do the following

- Move `mytable.ibd` to `\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data`
- Run the SQL to create the InnoDB table
- Login to mysql and run `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable DISCARD TABLESPACE;` (This will delete `\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mydb\mytable.ibd`)
- Copy `\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mytable.ibd` into `\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mydb`
- Login to mysql and run `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable IMPORT TABLESPACE;` (This will register `\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mydb\mytable.ibd` into the data dictionary)

After this, the table `mydb.mytable` should be fully accessible. You can test that accessibility by simply running:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable LIMIT 10;
```

Give it a Try !!!

### DRINK (Data Recovery Incorporates Necessary Knowledge) Responsibly

## Blatant copy of https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93511/189538

Not as part of MySQL, but tools like Percona Xtrabackup makes the process a bit faster for exporting/backing up the tables, allowing things like using regular expressions or lists for filtering:

- [Partial backups](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/innobackupex/partial_backups_innobackupex.html)
- [Restoring individual tables](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/innobackupex/restoring_individual_tables_ibk.html)

For importing a list of tables, you can use some automation oneliners like [this one found on Bill Karwin tools](https://github.com/billkarwin/bk-tools/blob/master/xtraimport):

```
mysqldump --no-data $schema > schema-ddl.sql
mysql -N -B <<'EOF' > discard-ddl.sql
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` DISCARD TABLESPACE;') AS _ddl
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='$schema' AND ENGINE='InnoDB';
EOF
mysql -N -B <<'EOF' > import-ddl.sql
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` IMPORT TABLESPACE;') AS _ddl
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='$schema' AND ENGINE='InnoDB';
EOF
```

Basically, you can use the `information_schema.tables` table for listing the tables you want using "dynamic sql". For example, change `$schema` above for the desired database name.