# What would happen if I delete the ibdata1 file in my mysql table and replace it with a new empty ibdata1 file?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a large database with hundreds of tables and over millions of records. I recently noticed that the ibdata1 file has a size of 360GB. It occupies a huge size in my server. I searched for several ways to reduce it and found it couldn't be shrunk.

Just for reference, what would happen if I just delete that ibdata1 file and create a empty new file in it's place...

Edit:
In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222583/what-if-i-delete-ibdata1-in-mysql-linux), the user deletes his file and unable to find older data after restarting the 'mysqld' service.

I'm planning to delete the old ibdata1 file and replace is with a empty ibdata1 file and want to know if it'll work.

Comment: yeah i checked that question but mine is different.. see the edit please

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "it'll work" - it certainly won't work the way that it did initially. You will lose all of your data. Depending on your config, you'll lose table structure too, but that depends how you set up your innodb. You'll need to be more specific about what results you are expecting. Also your assertion that "it couldn't be shrunk" isn't really true - see this question for why and a possible solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql

Comment: If ibdata1 is missing when mysqld starts, it creates the file.  You will have no tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ibdata1` contains the InnoDB dictionary, which is vitally important for InnoDB.

If you delete it any access to a table will fail with this error:

`Table doesn't exist`